# Bring Up keyboard programatically on clicking of input field on XBox - UWP App (JS)

Tags: javascript, uwp

I have an input field in my UWP (Js) application. I want the keyboard to be brought up automatically, to avoid having the user to hit 'Gamepad A' over it. I have seen this in multiple Xbox apps including the store.

So far I have tried to click, focus on the element

`document.getElementById('inputField').click()`,

```
document.getElementById('inputField').focus()
```

I have also tried to send a Keydown event with the keycode for Gamepad A(195)

```
` var event = document.createEvent("Events");
event.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
event.view = document.defaultView;
event.ctrlKey = false;
event.keyCode = 195;
event.charCode = 195;
$("#inputelement")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

`

This also did not work.
What else can be done to programmatically bring up the keyboard on a UWP (JS) app for Xbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-interactions#software-keyboard) when we programmatically focus to a text input control the touch keyboard will not be invoked. So the behavior seems by design:

*If your app sets focus programmatically to a text input control, the touch keyboard is not invoked. This eliminates unexpected behaviors not instigated directly by the user. However, the keyboard does automatically hide when focus is moved programmatically to a non-text input control.*

So actually the defualt behavior is like this:"Depending on the device, the software keyboard appears when a text field or other editable text control gets focus, or when the user manually enables it through the Notification Center:"